# How can I call a function within a closure within a variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, firebug

I'm a newbie in java but the code is below the explanation
This is code from a game but the problem is: Take the navigator function, I click the navigator in the game and some sort of (ajax?) goes on and it gets logged. But when I use my FireBug console I cannot send a message with the functions above the return line.
**Essentially.. The only functions that ThisFunction.* shows is the ones returned at the bottom. How can I invoke the Navigator function? I've tried:**
ThisFunction.a.navigator(args here);

, but it says a is undefined.. it doesn't show in the autocomplete list either.

** I removed the code because it is from a game. Thanks for the help! **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somewhat nailed it on its head with this bit:

> The only functions that ThisFunction.* shows is the ones returned at the bottom

That is the expected and purposeful functioning of the language.

Short answer: You have to return out of the closure anything that you want to be externally accessible... That could be the a variable, or it could be an api that could itself access the a variable while keeping it private from the exterior.  This is called lexical scoping and it is your friend.

Example time:

```
var ThisFunction = (function() {
  var a = { navigator: "woot" };
  var b = function() {
    return a;
  }
});
ThisFunction.a; //a is null/undefined on the returned
ThisFunction.b; //b is defined yay
var aOUTSIDE = ThisFunction.b();
aOUTSIDE.navigator; // "woot"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

So the only things that can get at A are the things that were var'd up in the same "scope" as a.  So either you return A out of the scope or you return something from inside the scope that provides an API to either get at A, or to execute some of A's internals...

Comment: In the game, that function is accessed when I clicked the navigator but how can it be accessed by other functions that aren't even in the return or ThisFunction

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured it out. The complex permissions pushed me back.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it.  Anytime you hit a problem like that check the scoping... it is a feature of the language that you cannot peek into another scope (that is not in your parental scope tree)... so if you need to peek into a scope, then you need to either return that thing out, or return an accessor API etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `OTHERFUNCTIONSHERE` is, you can access it from within one of those functions, if they close over the variable `a` (why such cryptic var names by the way?). Otherwise, it's out of scope.

Comment: It doesn't matter; any function declared in the same scope as `a` will have access to `a` (and `a. navigator`), so if one such function is in `OTHERFUNCTIONSHERE`, you can access it from there.

Comment: I see.. there is a logging function that looks like it executes the command as well.

Comment: What do you mean by close?

Comment: A "closure" is a function that "closes over" the scope where it was defined, meaning it has access to that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Firebug, `ThisFunction.%a.navigator(... args)` should work (`.%` is a [Firebug-specific extension](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Closure_Inspector#Using_the_Command_Line) to the language). But as noted in other answers, it's impossible from pure JavaScript.